# Resolving IP-address to unexpected host name

Tags: dns, resolve, nslookup

Just now (4 hours ago) i buy dedicated server and install latest Debian on it. In my dns registrator admin panel I create **'A' record** like **s5.mydomain.com** points to dedicated server IP-address.

When i try to `nslookup` it returns:

```
Name:    ip105-242.onlyskill.eu
Address:  dedicated_ip_address
```

**ip105-242.onlyskill.eu**??? What a hell is that? I dont know anything about ip105-242.onlyskill.eu...

Why Name is not **s1.mydomain.com** and how I can change it (or just delete **ip105-242.onlyskill.eu** to leave Name empty)?

Comment: it's probably about PTR record

Answer (score 0):

[A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#A) records will let you go from name to ip address.
[PTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types#PTR) records will do the reverse.

PTR records are administered by the owner of the addressblock (your ISP).